# Laptop can't find my home wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

The laptop has Ubuntu 14.04, it shows neighbors networks and it was working fine before.  My phone and desktop connect to my home Wi-Fi with no problems.  This has happened a few times before but in an hour or so I can resolve the problem by rebooting.  It has been almost a day and it didn't fix itself.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac

sudo service networking restart
sudo service network-manager restart

ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

and:

```
iwconfig wlan0 txpower off
iwconfig wlan0 txpower auto
```

I rebooted after those were executed but it did nothing.

Comment: If you issue `sudo iwlist scan` does your network show up?  You might want to grep for your network depending on how many surrounding networks there are, there may be a lot of output.

Comment: nope, it doesn't show up there

Comment: switching the wireless channel fixed it

Comment: Voting to close.  Fixed as per comment by OP.

Comment: Go to your network settings, change the security to WPA or WPA2 for that particular network. If that still fails, try getting an update. This would be a software issue that is likely on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The OP answered the question themselves [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598470/laptop-cant-find-my-home-wifi-network#comment834046_598470):

> switching the wireless channel fixed it - [viale](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598470/laptop-cant-find-my-home-wifi-network#comment834046_598470)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
nmcli dev wifi
```

a simple, clean and elegant way to get what you need.